# Broke Wordpress Site, Http 500 Error - W3 Total Cache

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-error, w3-total-cache

I was clearing my cache a couple of weeks ago and since then I've been receiving a http 500 error every once in a while. So I've been messing around with it and following some guides and then it suddenly couldn't load at all anymore!

I backed all of it up using Wpbackitup but I can't seem to put it back to action.
Anyone knows what to do?
My domain: http://www.jorgvandeven.nl/

EDIT: Checked my ftp and it seems 3 folder have been changed since I can't access my site anymore.

They're all located in the Wp-content folder:

/wwwroot/wp-content/cache (Has W3 total cache data I think)

/wwwroot/wp-content/w3tc-config/ (Master.php has been changed)

/wwwroot/wp-content/themes (Index.php has been changed)

EDIT 2:
I might have changed something in .Htaccess

Comment: Sounds like it is an error within your .htaccess - If you set your .htaccess file back to default, does the website load?

Comment: How do I do this? Shall I post my current Htcaccess?

Comment: Yes, post your current .htaccess content

Comment: I think I've fixed it! Renamed my /wpcontents/plugins folder to plugins.deactivate and I can access it now. But I can't reactivate some essential ones now.

Comment: files appear to be missing or out of place. Please re-install plugin or remove wwwroot\wp-content\advanced-cache.php. 




W3 Total Cache Error: some files appear to be missing or out of place. Please re-install plugin or remove wwwroot\wp-content\db.php. 




W3 Total Cache Error: some files appear to be missing or out of place. Please re-install plugin or remove wwwroot\wp-content\object-cache.php.

Can I just remove these via ftp and change the plugins.deactivated back to plugins?